# Can the Vapnik-Chervonenkis inequality be generalised to non-zero-one error functions?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, vc-dimension

I learned about the VC inequality of the bound of difference between training errors and generalisation errors. The two places ([Stanford CS229 notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes4.pdf) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_theory#Theorem_(VC_Inequality))) where I read about the theorem both use the 0-1 loss function.

Since one normally uses cross-entropy instead of accuracy as loss functions in say basic learning models like linear or logistic regressions, I wonder if the VC Inequality can be generalised to other loss functions, or does the 0-1 loss function case serve as a "universal case" and imply the inequality holds for a range of other loss functions as well?

Answer (score 1):

The VC inequality is strictly for binary hypothesis classes ($  \{h:X \rightarrow \{0,1\}\}$ ) . It gives an upper bound of the absolute difference between the empirical and the true risk , when they are defined with respect to the 0-1 loss .The VC dimension it's defined for binary classifiers only.

However ,the inequality can be generalized to all the settings you mentioned using different complexity measures (like Rademacher complexity or pseudo-dimension).

See for example Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms by Shai Ben-David and Shai Ben-David (it's available online for free) or  Foundations of Machine Learning 
by Mehryar Mohri , Afshin Rostamizadeh and Ameet Talwalkar